# WCF Integration with Legacy Remoting Client

Tags: wcf, tcp, client, remoting, legacy

I am facing a problem.

Please explain if this is possible or not.

1) I created a Service Library (.Net 3.5)

2) I created a Windows Service (.Net 3.5), added ServiceHost and implemented my ServiceLibrary to work as a TCP Endpoint.

3) Next I created a Console Client (.Net 3.5) and tried to get data from my TCP Endpoint…(svcutil….proxy.cs generation). Worked absolutely fine.

4) I have a Windows Client(.Net 1.1). How do I configure it to use this new Service? I can't add Proxy.cs as it says that servicemodel cannot be found…

Comment: FYI, putting your question title in caps isn't going to get more attention, just irritate people.

Comment: sorry :( capslock was on..didnt notice...please help on the issue though...

Comment: is this now closed or do you have further issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a basicHttpBinding, which is backward compatible and can be consumed by a .net 1.1 client. You should be able to find plenty of useful examples on the web: [Consuming WCF with .Net 1.1 Basic Binding](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=consuming+wcf+with+.net+1.1+basic+binding&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&safe=images). For example, this [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/1f8c7fe9-784c-4beb-8d0f-060bf8bfc24f/) describes that binding and usage of Soap 1.1 to make it compatible with .Net 1.1.

For more details on different scenarios and the range of wcf configuration possibilities, try exploring this [CodePlex Link](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/), specifically the [Application Scenarios](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Application%20Scenarios&referringTitle=Home) section that provides details of different setups. I believe that you will require a basicHttpBinding rather than a netTcpBinding in order to work with legacy protocols. The netTCPBinding would assume that you have .NET 3.0 at both ends. See this [MSDN Bindings Link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your review.But your suggestion would mean that the Transport medium gets changed to Http from TCP right??..To explain more...my code in my 1.1 windows client application to get data from my service was..
TcpChannel tcpchannel = new TcpChannel();ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpchannel);IRequiredInterface Obj = Activator.GetObject(typeof(IRequiredInterface),"tcp://10.100.200.300:1000/MyExistingOldRemotingService")as IRequiredInterface;DataSet DS_MyData = Obj.GetMyData();
Now my new Service address is.."net.tcp://10.100.200.300:1000/MyExistingOldRemotingService".How to do it

Comment: Thanks Mate :( disappointed though...Actually I didnt want to use http for intranet access..hence the old client was created using tcp..helps in security and ofcourse is faster...Anyway will try to work with "Add Web Reference" now...Thanks.